# How do i change Excel auto-formatting dates added to tables as MM-DD-YYY (custom format)?

Tags: excel, formatting

## My problem

I have an Excel workbook that auto-formats the date field in my Excel tables to a custom MM-DD-YYYY format when adding new dates. This problem happens across all Excel-tables in my workbook. This happens when adding dates through VBA, and manually entering a new line for a table. When selecting a cell, the formula bar shows the correct format, DD-MM-YYYY. This does not happen when typing outside of tables (i.e. in a blank cell formatted as general). The format displayed in the number format editor under custom: m-d-yyyy.

### What i have tried

- Selecting the entire column and formatting as the short-date format (DD-MM-YYYY). Still reverts to the custom format when adding new data.

Comment: Do you have any code running in the file in the background, or do you have another file open which has that as the primary date format?

Comment: Additionally, is the file local, network, or online (e.g., sharepoint)?

Comment: There is no code running in the background ( i assume you are talking about something like workbook change events). The workbook has a lot of code in general, but i am not changing the formatting of any tables etc. The file is on a network drive, but i do not have this issue with any other workbooks.

Comment: I am suspecting that the error has something to do with Excel-tables auto-formatting new entries based on the format in the first data-row. Somehow i must have changed the default format, but i cannot figure out how to revert it, re-formatting the entire column does not help for some reason.

Comment: It could also be a general Excel-setting but i am out of ideas :-)